# how to filter results in a collection using "find()" method- php codeigniter application

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
 20         public function get_all_available()
 21         {
 22 
 23                 //connect to mongodb collection (i.e., table) named as ‘surfinme_index’
 24                 $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('testcollection');
 25                 $result=$collection->find('available' => false);
 26                 return json_encode(iterator_to_array($result));
 27         }
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Filename: models/Export_model.php

Line Number: 25

Backtrace:
```

I was trying to following the documentation found here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

Thanks.

Comment: if you're doing to down vote my question, pls at least tell me why so i can improve next time.

Comment: Before asking question You need to search if there is solution. [see the solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=syntax+error%2C+unexpected+%27%3D%3E%27+%28T_DOUBLE_ARROW%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap it in an array() call.

```
 $result=$collection->find(array('available' => false));
```